# Slice Json array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a long Json array which I want to slice (e.g. get a sub-array of first 100 objects as Json array).

I don't want to use json.loads(), slice from Python list and then json.dumps() back to Json since it hurts my performances.

I was thinking maybe there is another way to slice the Json array without all of that but couldn't find one. Any suggestion?

EDIT: this is how I checked that the json.loads() take 1.5 sec:

```
        start_deserialize = time.time()
        log_list = list(json.loads(log_list))
        end_deserialize = time.time()
        print("deserialize took = "+str(end_deserialize-start_deserialize))
```

And as I mentioned at the beginning, it is a very long Json array.

Comment: How does it *hurts* your performance? Have you tried it or are you pre-optimizing?

Comment: I tried. It take about 1.5 sec and it's too much

Comment: Maybe try a tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: Is this JSON coming from a server? Have you considered doing this on the server-side to avoid processing in the client? (I'm guessing you're trying to achieve some kind of pagination). If the JSON is in a file, if you can have each object occupy a single line, then you can read the first 100 lines of the file and work on those instead of parsing the whole string.

Comment: @MatiasCicero I'm trying to achieve some kind of pagination and I am doing all those operations in the server side. The Json array is save to session, not a file.

Comment: 1.5 seconds is really a long time for a computer. Either the json is awfully *huge* or you are counting additional time like a download time. Please explain *exactly* what you have tested and what are the points that you want to optimize. As the *standard* way would be to load the json and slice a Python list, you must explain why it is non an acceptable option for your use case.

Comment: If you're going to be 'randomly' accessing a large amount of data, load and parse it once, then keep an easy to slice list in memory and pick up only the slices you need when you serialize it back to send to the client.